# Docker-machine Port Forwarding on Windows not working

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I'm attempting to access my django app running within Docker on my windows machine. I'm using docker-machine. I've been taking a crack at this for hours now.

Here's my Dockerfile for my django app:

```
FROM python:3.4-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        gcc \
        gettext \
        vim \
        curl \
        postgresql-client libpq-dev \
    --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /home/
# add app files from git repo
ADD . server/
WORKDIR /home/server
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "8000"]
```

So that should be exposing (at least in the container) port 8000.

When I use the command `docker-machine ip default` I am given the IP 192.168.99.101. I go to that IP on port 8000 but get no response.

I went into the VirtualBox to see if forwarding those ports would work. Here is the configuration:

[image: VirtualBox port forwarding config]

I also tried using `127.0.0.1` as the Host IP. I also tried disabling the windows firewall.

Here's my command for starting the container:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 <imagename>
```

I am at a loss on why I am unable to connect on that port. When I run `docker-machine ls` the url it gives me is `tcp://192.168.99.101:2376` and when I go to that it gives me some kind of file back, so I know the docker-machine is active on that port.

Also when I run `docker ps` I get this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
5c00cc28a2bd        <image name>         "python manage.py run"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   drunk_knuth
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the server was running on `127.0.0.1` when it should have been running on `0.0.0.0`.

I changed the `CMD` line in the Dockerfile from

`CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "8000"]`

to

`CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`

and it now works.