# GItLab CI gives curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8090: Connection refused

Tags: shell, docker, curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci

The issue is I get the `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8090: Connection refused GItLab CI` error but this does not happen on my laptop where I get the source html of the webpage. The `.gitlab-ci.yml` below is a simple reproduction of the issue. I have spent numerous hours trying to figure this out - i'm sure someone else has also.

[image: GitLab Docker Runner Verbose]

Aside: This isn't a similar question - since they don't offer a solution.

GitLab Repo: https://gitlab.com/mudassir-ahmed/wordpress-testing-with-gitlab-ci/tree/another-approach but the only file it contains is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` shown below...

```
image: docker:stable

variables:
  # When using dind service we need to instruct docker, to talk with the
  # daemon started inside of the service. The daemon is available with
  # a network connection instead of the default /var/run/docker.sock socket.
  #
  # The 'docker' hostname is the alias of the service container as described at
  # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services
  #
  # Note that if you're using the Kubernetes executor, the variable should be set to
  # tcp://localhost:2375/ because of how the Kubernetes executor connects services
  # to the job container
  # DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
  #
  # For non-Kubernetes executors, we use tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  # When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
  # improved performance.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add curl
    #- hostname -i
    - docker container ls
    - docker run -d -p 8090:80 --name nginx-server kitematic/hello-world-nginx
    - curl localhost:8090 # This works on my laptop but not on a GitLab runner.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the answer from here : [gitlab-ci.yml & docker-in-docker (dind) & curl returns connection refused on shared runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570796/gitlab-ci-yml-docker-in-docker-dind-curl-returns-connection-refused-on-sha)

There are two ways to fix this :

Option 1: Replace `localhost` in `curl localhost:8090` with docker like this `curl docker:8090`

Option 2:

```
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    alias: localhost
```

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work for me, option 1 is also recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559660/gitlab-ci-runner-not-able-to-expose-ports-of-nested-docker-containers).

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work for me either. I use `$DOCKER_HOST` as suggested [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1909)

Answer (score 0):

```
 docker run -d -p 8090:80 --name nginx-server kitematic/hello-world-nginx
 curl localhost:8090 # This works on my laptop but not on a GitLab runner.
```

Assuming that is your code i think that you should somehow add some timeout between docker run and curl.

I have similar issues some time ago after starting docker container on gitlab runner machine i wasnt able to accces my url to. When i added command which check if container  is running for " about one minute " it resolved my problem.

"docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} " + containerName" but in order to do that check, you should add some additional script

Comment: hi, so you are proposing that I should add something like ```sleep 60``` before the curl command?

Comment: you can try and if that help just create simple bash script which will check if docker container running for approx 1minute

Comment: hope that this is the same issue, because if you are wait after run container manually, localhost is available ?

Comment: thats not the issue.. tried the pause and used docker inspect and the container state is running

Comment: so when you login to gitlab runner machine and try to use  curl -v localhost:8090 in command line/terminal  what result do you get ?

Comment: ill post a picture... but its the same thing

Comment: try to find the IP that your docker instance is using by:

    $  docker-machine ip default

Now that you know the IP address, try curl again. You can even have it evaluated within the command like so:

    $  curl http://$(docker-machine ip default):4000

Comment: I have done that in the past and still the same. Any particular reason u used port 4000 in your comment?