# Can't access Spring Boot with my docker image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I'm created a simple docker image with Spring Boot based on steps at https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/.

Apparently the application is running normally, but I can not access it through the Browser.

To get my docker image: docker push renanshin/gs-spring-boot-docker

Here's an image of the Spring Boot of my Docker image.

[Initialization of Spring Boot at my docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5r7w.png)

Comment: are you using the `-p` option on docker to expose the port of your application? Here there is a simple documentation: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: Yes, I'm used this command : docker run -t renanshin/gs-spring-boot-docker

Comment: I solved the problem. Not have any error with the docker process. I was trying to access by ip 127.0.0.1:8080, but using docker, I would have to use ip http://192.168.99.100:8080/. This was a silly mistake of mine.

Comment: You should also be able to access it on you local host. Both `localhost:port` and `127.0.0.1:port` should work. How are you running docker ? Which OS? What is your output for `docker ps ` ?

Comment: As mentioned in this answer [How do I access a spring app running in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52729289/9164010), to access a Spring Boot app running in a Docker container, you should not only expose the port with `-p`, but also make sure that the Spring webapp listens to the special IP `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @RenanShinIti That would suggest that you are using an old docker version, recent docker versions (even on Windows and MacOS) allow binding to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I deleted my answer since you commented first and may want to post an answer yourself: I think you're right that the OP is using the legacy distribution of "Docker toolbox" for Windows, which relies on `docker-machine`: in this case, `docker run -p 8080:8080` won't expose the service to `127.0.0.1:8080` on the Windows host, but to a different IP address. See also [this page of the online doc](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/).

Comment: @ErikMD No, go ahead and undelete your answer, and feel free to include my bit of information in there if you want too.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok! thanks :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my Docker client version is 18.03.0-ce and engine version is 18.09.0.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the screenshot provided by the OP, it seems [@MarkRotteveel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54208629/cant-access-spring-boot-with-my-docker-image#comment95273730_54208629) is right.

Namely, the OP is running Docker on Windows, probably using Docker Toolbox for Windows (the legacy distribution based on `docker machine`), and it happens that in this case, `docker run -p 8080:8080 …` won't expose the service to `127.0.0.1:8080` on the Windows host, but to a different IP address.

For details, see [this page of the online doc](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/) and [that other page](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/).