# Not able to hit my container with IP address on my host machine

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-container

I am running locally my docker container. The container basically is a web application.  I can establish communication from my host machine to the container by request the endpoint e.g. `POST http://localhost:2200/myservice/book` .

Then, I find out the IP address of my local machine `192.168.10.32`, I thought I could still communicate with the container on my host by replacing `localhost` to my IP address e.g. `POST http://192.168.10.32:2200/myservice/book . But I can't, the containerized web app can't be reached at all. Why is that? I am under a wifi network.

My firewall is actually off:
[image]

Comment: did you allow that port thru the firewall?

Comment: what command did you use to start the docker container?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I am using a Macbook, how to check that firewall thing?

Comment: @niko I use `docker-compose -p myWebApp up -d`

Comment: @Leem here is how to open a port under Mac OS X https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642

Comment: My firewall is in "off" status, do I still need to turn it on and configure?

Comment: @Leem in that case please post your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Did you double-check the IP address listened by Spring Boot is `0.0.0.0`? Otherwise I guess that this thread would amount to a duplicate of [How do I access a spring app running in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633726/how-do-i-access-a-spring-app-running-in-a-docker-container/52729289#52729289)

Comment: From where did you try to reach the container (same host, other machine but same network, from the internet)?

Comment: Your host IP (192.168.10.32) is a provate address, thats why you can communicate your machine with your container, but you cannot access you container from outside (internet), to do that you need to get your public IP address and forward a port or something to the address you want

Comment: @Henry from the same host I am trying to reach the container.

Comment: What does `docker-machine ip dev` return?