# Unable to access rest endpoint in a docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have following in my Dockerfile for a simple spring boot rest service project:

```
FROM openjdk:8

EXPOSE 8080

ADD /target/spotdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar spotdemo.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "spotdemo.jar"]
```

Image is build successfully, and I can launch container for it too:

> docker run -p 8080:8080 -t spotdemo-microservice
>
> ..........
>
> Started SpotDemoApplication in 3.256 seconds (JVM running for 4.005)

But trying to access endpoint from postman throws error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-04-15T15:08:43.218+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/hello"
}
```

What else I am supposed to do here?

Edit:

Controller is as:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public String hello() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

Call is as:

> http://localhost:8080/hello

Comment: hä? Are you actually handling the `/hello` endpoint? Show us the code of the controller as well for proper help. And what is the exact request you're sending (method and URL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633726/how-do-i-access-a-spring-app-running-in-a-docker-container).

But seems the answer is:

> add server.address=0.0.0.0 to application.properties